# TypeError: $(...).rss is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I am reading an RSS feed from feedburner, it works fine on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFHfn/100/) but when I add the code to my site, it gives an error -

--ERROR-

```
TypeError: $(...).rss is not a function 
entryTemplate: '<a href="{url}">{title}</a><br>'
```

--Code--

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

$("#events").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/google/lkRN", {
    limit: 4,
    layoutTemplate: '<span id="entries">{entries}</span>',
    entryTemplate: '{date} <a href="{url}">{title}</a><br>'
}).show();
});
</script>

<div id="events"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include the rss plugin in your page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sdepold.github.io/jquery-rss/src/jquery.rss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#events").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/google/lkRN", {
            limit: 4,
            layoutTemplate: '<span id="entries">{entries}</span>',
            entryTemplate: '{date} <a href="{url}">{title}</a><br>'
        }).show();
    });
</script>
```

In the fiddler under External Resouces the rss plugin is included

Comment: The fiddle uses `jquery.rss.js`. You (OP) don't.

Comment: RSS is returning a wierd date format which I am not able to Parse or even substring. **Sun, 24 Nov 2013 20:27:09 -0800** How can is show only Month and Date?